# Random Number Set Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, set

i need to take one random element from a set of int. I am trying to use the function `elemAt :: Int->Set a->a` but i need to randomly generate the Int which will be used in the first argument of `elemAt`, but i am having a problem because randomRIO is a monadic function. How can i use randomRIO in a funcion that returns an int?E.g:

```
function :: Int->Int
function i = x <- randomRIO(0,i-1)
```

What i am trying to do is something like this:

```
element set = elemAt (function (size set)) set
```

Comment: short answer you cannot (without *cheating* using `unsafePerformIO`) - so just be honest and return a `IO Int` (obviously `function` is not pure so it makes a lot of sense that Haskell don't want you to write this function)

Comment: also the syntax is of `<-` - it's just `function i = randomRIO (0,i-1)`

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell we want to know if our functions are pure - in your case you want to implement a function which is obviously not pure at all - it's random.

So you should be honest about this function and indicate this in the type. Now of course you can use `randomRIO` and in this case you indicate this by returning `IO`-computations.

Assuming you want to take random elements form `Data.Set`s it could look like this:

```
randomElement :: Set a -> IO a
randomElement set = do
   i <- randomRIO (0, size set - 1)
   return $ set `elemAt` i
```

for `Map`s, etc. it's similar

Comment: But this way i only can use the element in a monadic function. Is there other way i can use to remove a random element?

Comment: not exactly - you don't need the `IO` when you pass the random-generator along and there are special monads just for this but in the end you have to take this information/type along with you

Comment: I am using this in the second argument of forAll which is a function ::a->prop. Any monad can fit this?

Comment: why would you do that? quickcheck will give you random values anyway - but yes there is [`ioProperty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#v:ioProperty) for cases involving `IO`

Comment: Because i am making a property for a function which gets a set and an element. The set is randomly generated and then i want to take one of the elements already generated.

Comment: you probably should open another question for this - IMO this one is answered and this discussion is drifting away

Comment: There is really no reason to mentioned `unsafePerformIO` here, other than to say "don't" - this is certainly not a valid use in any sense.

Comment: Depending on what you're testing, it might be easier to generate two things: a set and an element and put the element in the set to ensure it's there. This way you end up with a randomly generated set and a random element from it.